# $(x)$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show that ideal generated by $x$, that is $(x)$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Now let $(x) \subset J \subset \mathbb{R}[x]$. To prove $(x)$ is maximal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ we have to show $J= \mathbb{R}[x]$

Now $(x)=\{x.f(x)| f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]\}$.
As $J \neq (x)$, so $J$ must contain a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n + ... +a_0$ where $a_0 \neq 0$. Now $f(x)=x\{a_n x^{n-1}+...+a_1\}+a_0$ so $f(x)=x.g(x)+a_0$ now $f(x),xg(x) \in J$ so $a_0 \in J$.

So we have $a_0 \in J$. Now i want to show from this $1 \in J$  so that $J=\mathbb{R}[x]$. How can i do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're basically there. Since $a_0 \neq 0$, the constant polynomial $a_0$ is a unit in $\Bbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: $a_0^{-1}\in\mathbb R\subset\mathbb R[x]$, so $1=a_0^{-1}\cdot a_0\in J$.

Comment: If $f(x)\in J$, then also $\frac{1}{a_0}f(x)\in J$, because $J$ is an ideal. Still, the first isomorphism theorem is more elegant: $\Bbb R[x]/(x)\cong \Bbb R$ is a field, hence $(x)$ is maximal.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks got it

Comment: @KentaS thanks got it

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thanks yeah that is alredy  I know , $\psi :\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\psi(f(x))=f(0)$ which is a surjection and $(x)$ is kernel